# NG-show based on select list

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get items to only show up if something is selected in a select list. I am trying something like this

```
<input ng-show="myDropDown==''" type="text">
```

I basically want logic saying if the drop down has anything selected, show this ^. I found that example for specifying the option selected, however I would just like do say if anything is selected show, and if nothing has been selected, hide.

There is a catch, however, these drop downs will be re-generated with $http based on other clicks, and it would be ideal if this was done that the text would hide. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<select ng-model="item">
  <option ng-repeat="item in items" value ={{item.name}}>
      {{item.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Then you can just check for item, like so:

```
<input ng-show="item != null" type="text">
```

Looks like there is an even easier way to define the select:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in items" 
   ng-model="selectedItem"></select>
```